# How to switch between 2 servers in the web.config file dynamically for MS VS2005 C# .Net 2.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I am seeking a way to switch between 2 connection strings in the web.config file for a C# web, database & report server application.  I was hoping to be able to construct the connection sting based on what web server is being used ( i.e. a production server or a development server).  I wanted to use the same connetion  string name in both cases, just put in the correct database name & password.  Is this possible ?  Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2010, [Config Transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) are the way to go.

However,

Since you're looking at Visual Studio 2005, you might take a look at [this blog post from Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx).